# How to fix a coefficient in an ordinal logistic regression without proportional odds assumption in R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I want to do an ordinal logistic regression in R without the proportionality odds assumption. I know this can be done directly using `vglm()` function in `R` by setting `parallel=FALSE`.

But my problem is how to fix a particular set of coefficients in this regression setup? For example, say the dependent variable $Y$ is discrete and ordinal and can take values $Y = 1$, $2$, or $3$. If the regressors are $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$, then the regression equations are

$$ \begin{aligned} 
{\rm logit} \big( P(Y \leq 1) \big) &= \alpha_{1} + \beta_{11}X_{1} + \beta_{12}X_{2} \\
{\rm logit}\big(P(Y \leq 2) \big) &= \alpha_{2} + \beta_{21}X_{1} + \beta_{22}X_{2} 
\end{aligned} $$

I want to set $\beta_{11}$ and $\beta_{22}$ to $1$. Please let me know how can I achieve this. Also if `R` can't do this, could you also please let me know if I can achieve this in any other statistical software?

Comment: Is $X_1$ continuous or categorical? If the latter, then you might get something close to what you want by running stratified analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter. Both X1 and X2 are continuous.

Comment: So is the point then, that you just want to optimize the fit of this model over alpha?

Comment: Not exactly. The model still has two betas to be estimated. The whole point is, is there a way I can fix a bunch of coefficients in this kind of regression setup, in R or any other statistical software?

Comment: I think you can use the `offset` command and use $X_2$ as the offset value. This works in several `R` generalized linear model and related functions.

Comment: I can't use offset() because it completely removes the corresponding regressor from the regression. But that's not what I want here.

Comment: @Shanker, if you want to fix the coefficient at $1$, then you don't want it in the model - you just want to add the corresponding variable to the right hand side of the equation, which is what offset does.

Comment: @Macro, Note that the ordinal logit regression has two equations in it. I want to fix the coefficient of a regressor in one equation and not in the other one. I can't see how offset can achieve this in a single formula.

Comment: @Shanker, sorry - I misread your quote **"I want to set $\beta_{11}$ and $\beta_{22}$ to $1$"** - I thought these corresponded to the same variable in both equations but I can see that is not the case. Someone may have the right `R` code to help you here but I suspect no such code exists and the answer to the question (which you may not want to hear), is to write your own code to fit this model. This wouldn't be terribly complicated and if you need help deriving the likelihood equations, etc. then you may consider posting that as a separate question.

Comment: Can the OP explain more clearly why `offset()` doesn't work here? That's generally how one fixes a parameter in models in R.

Comment: Make sure that the logit link is the one that fits best overall.  See the R `rms` package `orm` function for other links and Handouts in http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/CourseBios330 for a case study that examines 4 link functions (ordinal model families).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand what the OP meant when he/she says "I can't use `offset` because it completely removes the corresponding regressor from the regression." You can fix a parameter using the `offset()` function in R. I'm using `lm()` below, but it should work in your model as well.

```
dat  <- data.frame(x=rnorm(30))
dat$y <- dat$x * 2 + rnorm(30) 
free <- lm(y ~ x,dat)
fixed1<- lm(y ~ offset(2 * x),dat)

summary(free)
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)  0.03899    0.17345   0.225    0.824    
#x            2.17532    0.18492  11.764 2.38e-12 ***

summary(fixed1)
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)  0.05043    0.17273   0.292    0.772
```

The fixed parameter doesn't show up in the output, but it's still fixed at 2. Next I'll fix the `x` parameter to its estimated value in the `free` model

```
fixed2<- lm(y ~ offset(2.17532 * x),dat)
summary(fixed2)
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)  0.03899    0.17002   0.229     0.82
```

Notice the intercept in `fixed2` is estimated with the same value as in the `free` model.